# Type Ia supernova by fallback?

Tags: star, supernova, white-dwarf

Is it possible for a massive star of more than 1.4 solar masses (probably around 3 or more but below the threshold for type II) to collapse into a white dwarf and a planetary nebula, then go supernova as the ejected material falls back onto the white dwarf?

Edit: Have there been any candidates for such an event?

Comment: Why would the ejected material fall back?

Comment: Yes this is plausible, but uncertain. @PeterErwin the ejected matter might not have enough momentum to fully escape the gravitational potential of the collapsing star. https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1086/307119/fulltext/35822.text.html

Comment: @DaddyKropotkin That article is about "accretion-induced collapse", where the accreted matter comes via mass transfer from a close binary companion. It has nothing to do with whether planetary nebula ejecta could somehow fall back.

Comment: @PeterErwin "Fall back" is a rather vague phrase. An accretion disk could develop from the planetary nebula. https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/29102/why-do-nebulae-turn-into-accretion-disks-but-planets-do-not Also, if matter could be transferred to the WD from a companion, then one, perhaps naively, might expect that a planetary nebula or common envelope could induce accretion.